# echo "command" | at now - where does the output of command go

Tags: at-job

I have a code that does this. Command is a perl script. I don't see the output of that anywhere. Is there a log of at command somewhere which I can check. At is a the fairly common word so I get irrelevant hits on google. Man at does not give any information. Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try redirecting the output to a file for easy access:

```
echo "pwd >> /home/user/file.log" | at now
```

Answer (score 0):

stdout goes to users mail (root?)

careful
command | at now   --- yields: the output of the command goes to the "at" program and likely mail will show errors

echo "command" | at now   --- yields: the "at" program will execute "command" and stdout will nicely show in mail